# SQL Server : is there a way to process changetracking in batches

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

Let's say I have change tracking enabled on `tblUser`. Then I can get all changes like this:

```
select *
from changetable(changes tblUser, @last_sync_version) ct
left join tblUser u on ct.UserID = u.UserID
```

This can return too many rows, so I'd like to get changes in a loop, in batches of let's say a 1000 rows at a time:

```
select top 1000 *
from changetable(changes tblUser, @last_sync_version) ct
left join tblUser u on ct.UserID = u.UserID
order by ct.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION
```

The issue with the above is that SYS_CHANGE_VERSION is not unique. If multiple users where modified in one sql transaction, their changes will have the same SYS_CHANGE_VERSION. If 1001 changes have the same SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, passing max(SYS_CHANGE_VERSION) from the current loop iteration, as @last_sync_version for the next iteration, will result in the next iteration skipping the 1001st change.

Is there a way to achieve reading changetracking data in batches?

Comment: select top 1000 with ties * .... perhaps help you

Comment: That was it! Thanks @TriV.

Comment: You're welcome. @Andrew